# Hibernate criteria like is not giving appropriate result

Tags: hibernate

Is *like* be used with string parameters only or can I use it for integers as well? That is, I want to list all the numbers in REQ_ID column of my table called DATASTACK starting from any inputted number suppose 1. Then criteria.add(Restrictions.*like*("REQ_ID", 1, MatchMode.START)); would work in my case or not?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Like operator is not applicable for integers. If at all you need to run this query, an alternative would be to change the data type of REQ_ID to varchar2 instead of number (that is, String instead of Integer in your entity class)

Comment: Thanks. But is there anything other than ilike or like, that could work with integers?